# Which one is correct, "through" or "by providing" one-on-one support?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

- I built positive relationships through one-on-one support
- I built positive relationships by providing one-on-one support.

Or are they both grammatically correct.

Comment: Can you give some more details of why you think there is a problem here?  Have you found any examples of "through one-on-one support" and "by providing one-on-one support" in a websearch?

Comment: @JamesK, I haven't found any examples. I'm an over-thinker/perfectionist, and I'd thought the phrase "by providing one-on-one support" sounded incorrect. It's for a cover letter.

Comment: The problem is that they do not mean the same. The first one could in theory refer to receiving support rather than providing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to find examples of both

> We help people develop basic digital skills *through one on one support* given by volunteers.

> We will be working together to support new teachers *through one-on-one support*, team meetings, and in online forums.

> You’ll assist local teachers *by providing one-on-one support* to students struggling with class concepts.

> Senior Companions allow fewer staff to serve more clients *by providing one on one support* to the clients in the most need.

(all these examples were on page one of a google search for the phrases)

I'd prefer "by providing", since that seems to be the idiom used in resumés. But both are used.